# Difference between Element.insertAdjacentText() and HTMLElement.innerText

Tags: javascript

`insertAdjacentHTML()` and `innerHTML` have a small but very important difference (["[...] making insertAdjacentHTML() much faster than direct innerHTML manipulation"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML)).

Are there any performance or security implications or any other significant differenes considering `Element.insertAdjacentText('afterbegin', txt)` and `HTMLElement.innerText = txt` for **empty** DOMs beside the extra capability of `insertAdjacentText()` to insert text before or after the calling Element? They seem to have different calling DOM element classes (Element vs HTMLElement)...